# Tensor flow directory syntax

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I try to execute the code in google collab to quantize my tensor flow model in my PC

In the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(D:\FYP\tflite floating point model converted_tflite\converted_tflite)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8  # or tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8  # or tf.uint8
tflite_quant_model = converter.convert()
```

The error said it is syntax problem in

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(D:\FYP\tflite floating point model converted_tflite\converted_tflite)
```

Is it syntax problem? Or is google colab cannot execute my local file and I must do this by downloading python?
How should I write directory syntax correctly in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot to pass the path as a string (notice the use of `"`):

```py
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("D:\FYP\tflite floating point model converted_tflite\converted_tflite")
```